# SQL Rank syntax for using multiple columns to rank by

Tags: sql, rank, row-number, dense-rank

I am trying to do ranking based on 2 columns and also when it comes to a tie, differentiate them based on the other column.I have put together the below table to explain my question. So I want to rank the players based on their scores per game with in their team, and if they come to a tie, I want to rank them based on their scores per year, still within their team.  How can I achieve that with a sql query? Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you in advance!
[image: base table][image: expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
rank() over (partition by team order by scores_per_game desc, scores_per_year desc)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I am going to try that.